# YII : Ajax database update in ClistView

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, yii

I want to update a record in my database based on a click in Yii. I have tried various methods but the request is not being posted by the button.

Here is my ajax button Code

```
CHtml::ajaxButton('Done',Yii::app()->createUrl('task/updateTask'),
                    array(
                        'type'=>'POST',
                        'data'=> array('id'=>$data->task_id),                        
                        'success'=>'js:function(string){ alert(string); }',

                    ),array('class'=>'btn btn-success',));
```

The request is sent via POST method to the Controller and the code for controller is

```
public function actionupdateTask(){                    
            $query = "UPDATE task SET task_status=4 WHERE task_id=:t_id";
                $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
                $command->bindValue(':t_id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
                $command->execute();
                 Yii::app()->end();

        }
```

But the button is not working or sending data. If i check the source of the page it shows

```
jQuery('#yw0').yiiListView({'ajaxUpdate':['yw0'],'ajaxVar':'ajax','pagerClass':'pagination','loadingClass':'list-view-loading','sorterClass':'sorter','enableHistory':false});
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt0',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':{'id':'5'},'success':function(string){ alert(string); },'url':'/tasks_yii/index.php?r=task/updateTask','cache':false});return false;});
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt1',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':{'id':'4'},'success':function(string){ alert(string); },'url':'/tasks_yii/index.php?r=task/updateTask','cache':false});return false;});
jQuery('body').on('click','#yt2',function(){jQuery.ajax({'type':'POST','data':{'id':'1'},'success':function(string){ alert(string); },'url':'/tasks_yii/index.php?r=task/updateTask','cache':false});return false;})
```

it seems ok but it is not working.

Comment: can you see if the request has been launched or not in the console?

Comment: i saw it in firebug console , but nothing is being sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem has now been solved, it was due to the non closure of script tag which blocked the other scripts and which in turn prevented all the ajax calls made

Answer (score 1):

You shuld replace `actionupdateTask` with `actionUpdateTask`

```
public function actionUpdateTask(){                    
    $query = "UPDATE task SET task_status=4 WHERE task_id=:t_id";
    $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($query);
    $command->bindValue(':t_id', $_POST['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $command->execute();
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```